# Need a function to identify co-prime pairs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, functions, gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given an odd number $\,n,\,$ I'm trying to find a way to map natural numbers $\,k\,$ onto a set of
$\large{\text{odd}}$ numbers $\,j\,$
where $\,GCD(n,j)=1.\quad$ In the table below, I have had to skip $\,k$-values $\,(3,5,6,9,10,12,15)\,$ for the composite number $\,15=3\cdot5.$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k& GCD(n,k) & j \text{ need} & j-k\text{ diff}\\ \hline
15& 1 & 1 & 1  & 0 \\ \hline
15& 2 & 1 & 2  & 0\\ \hline
15& 3 & 3 & 4  & 1\\ \hline
15& 4 & 1 & 7  & 3 \\ \hline
15& 5 & 5 & 8  & 3 \\ \hline
15& 6 & 3 & 11 & 5 \\ \hline
15& 7 & 1 & 13 & 6 \\ \hline
15& 8 & 1 & 14 & 6 \\ \hline
15& 9 & 3 & 16 & 7 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If $\,n\,$ were prime we could use a simple funcion like
$j=k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(n-1)}\bigg\rfloor\,$
because the floor component need only skip single non-coprime values of $\,k\,$ in favor of co-prime values of
$\,j.$ The problem with composite $\,n$-values is that there must be a look-ahead of sorts because there can be more than one non-coprime $\,(n,k)\,$ pair in a sequence.
I want to map
$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,\cdots\}$$
onto
$$\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14,16,17,19,22,23,26,28,29,\cdots\}$$ I have tried such as the following where
$\,p_1, p_2,\cdots\,$ are prime factors of $\,n\,$ but it has no ability to look ahead.

\begin{align*}
j=k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k)}{(p_1)}\bigg\rfloor
+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k)}{(p_2)}\bigg\rfloor+\cdots\
 \end{align*}

It appears that there can be as many sequential non-coprime $\,(n,k)\,$ pairs as there are prime factors of $\,n.\,$ How do I look ahead to tell how mny additional number skips are needed? A program could do it but how do I put that logic into a function?

Comment: $\left\lfloor\frac{16}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{16}{5}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{16}{15}\right\rfloor=5+3-1=7$

Comment: @Daniel Mathias The problem is I won't know about the $16$ because all I hve is $k=9$.